# Do I need to sanitise TIPTAP text editor in nextJS?

Tags: next.js, sanitization, sanitize, tiptap, sanitizer

do I need to sanitise TIPTAP text editor with nextJs? If so, what sanitiser is best with nextJS and TIPTAP text editor?

Answer (score 0):

From TipTap docs:

> "[...]if there are some tags or attributes that aren’t allowed (based
> on your configuration), Tiptap just throws them away quietly."
> https://tiptap.dev/guide/output

You should still sanitize on the server, before saving to db. You can use
[https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html#default-options) or similar package.